# Kinetic Typography

Tags: typography

Is there anyone that knows a not so expensive way (I don't want to purchase FinalCut or something alike) to create something like ...
[this: Fight Club](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuiKJ0rRTAo)
or 
[this: V for Vendetta](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6Q0dfrbr10)
or anything from [here](http://joaobordalo.com/articles/2007/08/15/top-12-kinetic-typography-films)

As far as I know It's CS3. I'm search for something less expensive. I'm on a mac with Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having seen these videos before, most were created with a combination of Photoshop and AfterEffects.  Photoshop can be replaced with Pixelmator or The GIMP, but AfterEffects doesn't have a consumer-level equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Blender, but it is not made for this kind of animation, and it will be slightly harder to animate than with After Effects. Create some text and make sure you make it unaffected by lights. See www.blender.org